# Python decorate method with callable outside parent class

Tags: python, decorator

Let's assume I have a class to be used as a decorator like such:

```
class specialmethod:
  def __init__(self,func):
     self.func = func

  def __call__(self,arg1,arg2):
     print arg1,arg2
     self.func(arg1,arg2)
```

But the method being decorated is within another class, that also must utilize `self` (the values within self are relevant to the function body post-decoration)

```
class A:
  @specialmethod
  def dosomething(self,data,otherdata):
    #this guy down here isn't getting the right value for self, an instance of A
    print type(self)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deco.py", line 18, in <module>
    a.dosomething('foo','bar')
  File "deco.py", line 7, in __call__
    self.func(arg1,arg2)
TypeError: dosomething() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Is there anyway to preserve the way `self` would work if it were not decorated?  I've tried passing it explicitly but it still expects the wrong number of parameters.

**EDIT**

I should clarify that the intended value for self in the final function body of `dosomething` should refer to the instance of `A`... not looking to get the decorator instance into the decorated function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use a class like a decorator, you have to realize that the normal magic that turns functions into methods (the descriptor protocol, specifically the `__get__` method) won't work for your class unless you explicitly implement it. You could do this manually, by implementing a `__get__` method that returns a new type that remembers the instance it was retrieved from as well as the actual callable to call, but it's a lot of work for very little gain.

A more common approach is to not use an actual class as a decorator, and always have the decorator return an actual Python function. In this particular case, there isn't really a point in keeping the class at all, so you could just do:

```
def specialmethod(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(arg1, arg2):
        print arg1, arg2
        f(arg1, arg2)
    return wrapper
```

... but if you really want to keep the class, you can do so by doing something like:

```
class _specialmethod:
  def __init__(self,func):
     self.func = func

  def __call__(self,arg1,arg2):
     print arg1,arg2
     self.func(arg1,arg2)

def specialmethod(f):
    wrapper_class = _specialmethod(f)
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapper(arg1, arg2):
        wrapper_class(arg1, arg2)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Would the first method still work even if the function being decorated is a method within a class?  The additional `self` before the two args is implied?

Comment: Both ways work if the function being decorated is a method in a class; in both cases, `arg1` is the parameter that receives the instance, what `self` would be in the wrapped function. (I copied the naming from your example, but normally you use `*args, **kwargs` in both the wrapper definition and the call to `f`. In that case, `self` is the first item in the `args` tuple.)

Comment: Worked great, thanks!  One last question, would behave differently if the method being decorated is one of `A`'s magic methods, like `__call__`?

Comment: Nope, the decorator returning a function means that the result is a completely regular Python version, and Python can't tell the difference between the original function and the decorated function. It works entirely the same.

Comment: Why do you need functools.wraps ?